# Save changes in 2 different folders using VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to setup 2 folder in my local hdd so I can: code/edit files in folder1 with VSCode, and from there, only when I decide to save changes, they are applied to folder1 + folder2?
Folder1 is used to pull/push/edit code, while folder2 functions just as a backup that keep tracks of **only** the saves I want from VSCode file/files in which I'm working on (so folder1 files are the ones up to date, folder2 files are dated only to the last save I decided to keep/save from VSCode).

It something like this possible? Is it possible to do it, when configured, with a "simple" hotkey? Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: Couldn't you just setup a script that copies folder 1 to 2 and whenever you want that backup, just save, then run your script? Alternatively, with Free File Sync, you can make one folder be a mirror of another folder, and every time a file is overwritten or deleted, instead of deleting it, move the old version to a different folder, so you always have a backup of every version up to x days old.

Comment: @LPChip thanks for the answer. Actually I've never heard of Free File Sync, but seems something similar to what I'm looking for. I was hoping I could do everything inside VSCode (somehow) without having to rely on external softawares. Is this the most common software to do this kind of "backup"? Thanks meanwhile

Comment: Its actually software designed for something else that works really well as a backup tool. It basically got expanded with features. I use it on my fileserver to make it ransomware proof. My main share is accessible in the network and could get encrypted. The server runs the folder monitoring version of Free File Sync and whenever a file changes, it copies that to my external drive. Every file that is deleted is moved to another folder on my external drive. So its all automatic.